# Computing for a number using two different percentage category.

Tags: percentages

I've come across a government document on a profile of a city, and have been curios to how to solve for this or if there's already a named formula for it.

City X

- Land Area: 49800 ha .
- Alienable Area: 1,883.21 ha., which is 3.78% of 49800

Now, one barangay(smallest administrative division in the Philippines) of the city has the following data.

Barangay A

- Land Area: 11332 ha.,    which is 22.76% of 49800

Is it possible for me to compute the alienable area of Barangay A using the Alienable Area of the City along with the Land Area of Barangay A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do here is use simple unitary method. This assumes that the Alienable area is spread uniformly across the City X.

So if $1883.21$ ha of Alienable land is present in $49800$ ha, then the city of Barangay contains:

$$\frac{1883.21}{49800} \times {11332}\text{  ha}$$

Alienable land.